# Issues Multiprocessing with Queues

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Situation: I have a file processor written in Python. The files will be "walked" and be put into a queue. It will then be processed using `multirocessing`

Problem: Refer to the code below

```
fileA.py
==========
import Queue
import os
def walker():
    filelist = Queue.Queue()
    queue_end = Object()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
        for f in files:
            path = os.path.join(root,f)
            if not os.path.islink(path):
                filelist.put(path)
    filelist.put(queue_end)

fileB.py
===========
import fileA
import os
import multiprocessing as mp

def processor(queuelock):
    while True:
        with queuelock:
            filepath = fileA.filelist.get()

            if filepath is fileA.queue_end:
                filelist.put(queue_end)
                break
        #example of a job
        os.move(filepath, "/home/newuser" + filepath)
        print filepath + " has been moved!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fileA.walker()
    queuelock = mp.Lock()
    jobs = []
    for i in range(0,mp.cpu_count()):
        process = mp.Process(target=processor(queuelock))
        jobs.append(process)
        process.start()
```

The problem is when the files are being moved, all processes will attempt to move the EXACT same file, even though it has supposedly been removed from the queue.

Example output:

```
randomFile as been moved!
Error: ......... randomFile not found
Error: ......... randomFile not found
Error: ......... randomFile not found
```

Thereby implying that every process spawned has dequeued the exact same file and tried to perform the same process on the same file.

Question: Is there something that I am doing wrong that for some reason, the `filelist` queue has been sent to every process (what is happening now), instead of the `filelist` queue being shared by all process (my intended result)?

Comment: (1) `filelist` seems to be local only and isn't sent (or forked) anywhere. (2) Use `mp.Queue` as queue implementation.

Comment: `mp.Queue` it caters more for multi-access?

Comment: If the queue is accessed from multiple processes then `mp.Queue` is needed, otherwise you have independent queues for each process.

Comment: Alright. understood. Thank you very much

Comment: You want to put it as an answer an I'll accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `filelist` is currently only a local variable to `walker()` and the queue object isn't shared with other parts of the code, so at least a `return filelist` is needed in `walker()`.
2. To share the same queue among multiple processes, a `multiprocessing.Queue` is needed. A `queue.Queue` is copied when a process is forked (or spawned) so it becomes a new indepent queue for each process.